# How to take 3 integer input (if possible through slider) whose sum is <= 100 Jsp form?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have 3 power ups.
While registration i want that user to choose the combination such that some of all 3 is less than 100.

I tried sending the data to servlet and redirecting back if the sum is larger than 100. Want a better approach

In jsp(index.jsp):

```
<form action="Register" method="POST">
                User Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="UserName">
                <br />
                Password : <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                xdamage:<input type="text" name="xdamage" placeholder="xdamage">
                <br />
                xhealth:<input type="text" name="xhealth" placeholder="xhealth">
                <br /> 
                xpotion:<input type="text" name="xpotion" placeholder="xpotion">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" >
            </form>
```

In servelet(Register)

```
    String s1 = request.getParameter("name");  
    String s2 = request.getParameter("pass");
    String s3 = request.getParameter("xdamage");
    String s4 = request.getParameter("xhealth");
    String s5 = request.getParameter("xhealth");

if(Integer.parseInt(s3) + Integer.parseInt(s4) + Integer.parseInt(s5) > 100)
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

Comment: well i tried sending the data to servlet and redirecting back if the sum is larger than 100. Want a better approach.

Comment: post the code you have tried and explain how do you want us to improve your code

Comment: @SrinathGanesh
Have posted what i am doing now.
I want that this is done in the jsp page itself and dont want it to redirect.
If possible I want the 3 inputs to be done by the slider also the 3rd slider auto adjusts itself to make sum 100 or atleast doesnt go all the way.

Comment: you can make one jsp page call another jsp page(replacing servlet) , ** but it does redirect ! ** jsp is compiled to servlet indirectly . so you can call from a jsp page to itself . ie form to java code

Comment: s5 may have xpotion .. you have repeated xhealth in getParameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to check sum of 3 fields to provide user-friendly interface and after submit check the same logic in backend for fields validation.

Comment: @karx , if you are using this answer then : dont forget to check at both server and client : javascript may be disabled